# How to prevent people or a program from extracting data out of a system?

Tags: export, bots, extract, data-extraction, vdi

Let us say, there is a system containing data, where the user can view or manipulate it, using the options in the system, but should not be able to copy/ extract/ export the data out of the system. Also, any bots such as RPA or crawlers should not be exporting too. The data strictly recides in the system.

Eg: VDI - [Virtual Desktop Infrastructure](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/virtual-desktop-infrastructure-vdi), does some sort of this work. People can connect to remote machines and do some work, but cannot extract data out of it to their local machine, unless it allows the user to do so. Even RPA bots will not be allowed to run in that remote system, only can be run in local system but it will be tedious to build such a bot, providing a closer solution to the above problem.

I am just looking for alterate light-weight options. Please let me know, if there is any solution available.

Comment: What interface is used by user for data viewing and manipulating? What methods of data copy/ extract/ export are available in the system? What access protocols, APIs or runtime environments are available for bots? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no way of stopping all information export.
A user could just take a photo to the screen and share the info.
If by exporting you mean exporting files, then simply do not allow  exporting the files in your program or restrict the option, if you need to store data on the disk, store it encrypted.
The best options would be to configure a machine only to use that software, so on boot it would lauch the software fullscreen, deny any usb autorun keys and have something like Veyon insyalled to be remotely controlled and have some config data on the disk but pretty much all the data on a remote server.
If you need a local cache, you can keep it encrypted.
That said theoretically if a user had access to the ram physically, he/she could retrieve that data but it is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have to make ssh and ftp useless! this is to prevent scp or other ftp software from being used to move things from inside the system out and vice versa, block ports 20, 21 and 22!

If possible, I'd block access to cloud storage services (DNS/Firewall), so that no one with access to the machine would be able to upload stuff to common cloud services or if you have a known address that might be a potential goal for your protected data. Make sure that online code repositories are also blocked! if the data can be stored as text, it can be also transfered to github/gitlab/bitbucket as a normal repo... you can block them also at DNS level. Make sure that users don't have the previlage to change network settings, otherwise they can bypass your DNS blocks!

You should prevent any kind of external storage connectivity.. by disallowing your VM from connecting to the server's USB ports or even bluetooth if exists.

That's off the top of my head... I'll edit this answer if I remember any more things to block.